# Inno Setup: How to create a menu list depending on already existing users files

Tags: inno-setup

I've spent countless hours on this and still I have no clue how to solve:

**I try to detect a specific existing user files in order to automatically select an installation option determined by the [types] section.**

My program has to install different files whether program A, B or C is installed on the user's file system. At the moment I've got a [Components] list containing all installable components and a [Types] list with the appropriate entries. The user can (has to) select the Program he has installed (A, B or C) first, then his version. What I'm looking for is a solution of how I can automatically show the specific installable components (versions) depending on the already installed program (A, B or C).

**Tl;dr:**

Program A is installed -> installable versions for A are shown automatically (same if B or C is installed)

(hope I could make this clear as I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: I dont know if it is possible to do that by only using COMPONENTS and TYPES Section of inno setup. I would solve it by creating custom pages. In such a custom page you can take the input of the user (Wwhich program is already installed) and show in the next custom  setup page which of your new stuff need to be installed. Is there a way to identify the already installed software e.g. by detecting special folders or registry entries? If so you can check this when your setup starts and offer only the stuff which can be installed then. So I guess there a many ways to solve it...

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try it out with custom pages.

Comment: which bit are you stuck on? What do you have working so far? Detecting Program A/B/C? Getting Inno to change what's installed based on that detection? The UI?

Comment: I've tried to write a function using 'FileExists()' similar to Miral's answer (btw thank you!). Yesterday my task has changed a little. I have >40 components (MyProgramForA2007x86, MyProgramforA2007x64,...)belonging to 6 Types (Program A - F). Now I need to write a function which lists ALL already installed files on C:\ so I can identify and show a list of his installed programs including installation paths so the user can choose which type of my program he likes to install. ATM he has to manually choose from >40 options (which are reduced by [types])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Components]
Name: A; Description: Support for Program A; Check: HasProgramA
Name: B; Description: Support for Program B; Check: HasProgramB
Name: B\b1; Description: Version 1
Name: B\b2; Description: Version 2
Name: B\b3; Description: Version 3 Special Edition; Check: HasProgramBSpecial

[Code]
function HasProgramA(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (some calculations that return True if program A is installed);
  // eg. use the RegQuery* functions to read registry values
end;

// repeat for the other Check functions
```

This will display the Components only if their corresponding programs are installed, according to whatever criteria you come up with to determine that.